# Regex for two words in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, regex

Basically I'm trying to code a regex that will accept two words and nothing else, the words can contain any letters, but not numbers.

I've currently got:

```
^[a-zA-Z+#-.0-9]/s^[a-zA-Z+#-.0-9]$
```

Although I know for sure this is wrong because it isn't allowing two words separated by a space, it also currently allows numbers.

Does anybody know what Regex code I need to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick! :)

```
//Allow letters and numbers
^\w+\s\w+$ 

//Allow only letters
^[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: Hah! You beat me because I had only 27 chars in my reply at first ;)

Comment: ummm - what ever happened to the `but not numbers` requirement?

Answer (score 2):

While something using the `\w` shorthand character class *might* work for you, you specifically wrote `can contain any letters, but not numbers`, so you'd have to use:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Your expression allows numbers (and `+` and any of these characters: `#$%&*()-',.`) because you included all of these characters in your character class `[a-zA-Z+#-.0-9]`, which means lowercase and uppercase letters, `+` sign, any ASCII characters from `#` to `.` (which includes `$%&*()-',`), and any numbers `0-9`.

The shorthand character class `\w` allows letters, numbers, and underscore (`_`)

I might recommend running through a short tutorial on regex before deciding its the solution for you...

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
^\w+\s+\w+$
```